# How do you conveniently type Cmd+? on a Mac keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I've just migrated to a Mac. (Macbook with Magic Keyboard.) I'm having trouble coding because I can't find any sane way of typing Cmd+C, Cmd+V, etc..

How do most Mac programmers type these? By moving the whole hand so the pinky is on Cmd? By putting the thumb under the index finger?

Answer (score 1):

Command-c and Command-v are simple enough. I just use thumb and forefinger since c and v are close to the command key. If you meant capital c and capital v, I would use the same method but put my pinky on the shift key. There is no "acceptable" method, just use whatever you can or what feels right.

Comment: Thanks! I know there's no 'accepted' method, but it's really useful to know that you can get used to putting your thumb under your other fingers.